# Variable that equals document.getElementById and use it like jQuery's $?

Tags: javascript

Is there any reason I can't create a `var $ = document.getElementById` and then use it like jQuery's `$`?

Comment: u need to use `var $ = document.getElementById`

Comment: Creating a variable with the name `$` doesn't make it an jquery object.

Comment: @tkausl, Right, I just want to use it in vanilla javascript to call ```document.getElementById```

Comment: In this case, `var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);` would probably be better.

Comment: I just want a short, quick way to get element's by their id as I do it quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions care about the value of `this`. `getElementById` is one of them.

When you call `document.getElementById` the value of `this` inside the function is `document`.

When you detect the method from the `document` object and call it independently, it isn't, and the function throws an error.

You would need to create a new function which calls `getElementById` in the context of `document`:

e.g.

```
const x = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

or

```
const x = id => document.getElementById(id);
```

---

Of course, the *behavior* of `getElementById` is different to jQuery, so making a short variable name which calls it won't give you the same result as jQuery's `$`.

Comment: And then I could us ```x``` to ```x("element-name")...```?